# acts_as_taggable undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with acts_as_taggable (I did the migration well, etc.).

My view (in software form):

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.to_s %>
```

Software/Controller :

```
def software_params
  params.require(:software).permit(:tag_list)
end
```

Model/controller :

```
acts_as_taggable
```

But I am getting this error while submitting the form :

```
NoMethodError in SoftwaresController#update
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

My softwares/controller update

```
def update
  if @software.update(software_params)
    if params[:images]
      params[:images].each do |i|
        @software.screenshots.create(image: i)
      end
    end
    @screenshots = @software.screenshots
    redirect_to edit_software_path(@software)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Which version of RoR do you use?

Comment: I use Rails 5.2.0

Comment: Try to update gem `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', github: 'Fodoj/acts-as-taggable-on', branch: 'rails-5.2'` to this version. It is a known issue https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/pull/872

Comment: Thx you very much Artem !